# 'System' occupies 100 GB - why? How can I reduce the amount of data? (macOS 10.13 High Sierra)

Tags: macos, ssd, storage, disk-space, high-sierra

[image]

[image]

Any idea why is system taking so much space? Also the free space + used space on my system is not showing correct data. It shows available space is 154.76 GB and when I add the used space (171 GB) it goes beyond the capacity of my internal SSD.

**Any suggestions to why is my Mac showing such behaviour?**

Comment: @oa-
If you go to `/Applications/Utiltities` and launch `Terminal.app`, then type this command in:
`du -hc -d 1 /Library/`

What is the output?